# go get downloads unneeded dependency

Tags: go

One of my pipelines (GitLab CI) recently started breaking with a dependency no longer being available:

```
 $ go get
package github.com/go-resty/resty/v2: cannot find package "github.com/go-resty/resty/v2" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/go-resty/resty/v2 (from $GOROOT)
    /go/src/github.com/go-resty/resty/v2 (from $GOPATH)
```

I didn't recognize the package as one that we are using, so I tried to find out which dependency we're using that, in turn, depends on this package.

After checking all my deps, I cannot find a dependency on this package. I've checked all the external dependencies my own system has, which are the below ones:

```
"github.com/golang/protobuf/proto"
"github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes"
"github.com/pkg/errors"
mgo "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
"gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
"golang.org/x/net/html/charset"
"github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery"
imap "github.com/emersion/go-imap"
"github.com/emersion/go-imap/client"
"github.com/sajari/docconv"
```

I've also used tools such as [godepgraph](https://github.com/kisielk/godepgraph) to try to find nested deps. However, nothing I can find includes the package from the error.

How can I find out why this package is downloaded when running `go get`?

Comment: Are you using Go modules to manage dependencies?

Comment: Use `go mod why` to find who is importing it. If it is unused: delete from go.mod

Comment: Remove unused dependencies with `go mod tidy`.

Comment: @Adrian I'm not using go modules, just go get. @Volker I get `go: modules disabled inside GOPATH/src by GO111MODULE=auto; see 'go help modules'`. Started reading it, but it's a long read, so I'll get back to you if there's anything I can do with that information.

Comment: If you're not using modules then `go mod` commands aren't going to help you. It's a transitive dependency of something you're importing, `go list` will confirm that, but I don't think it will tell you what the source of the dependency is.

Comment: Alright. Yeah, `go mod`, of course gives me `go: cannot find main module` and `go list` just outputs the name of my own main package. I assume, then, that the problem is that the go module is not updated for one of my deps. I'll try to set `export GO111MODULE=off` in my pipelines and see if it solves the issue.